# Alternative for IsMDIContainer in Windows 6.5 Mobile Application?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I think IsMDIContainer is not available for Windows 6.5 mobile applications.

What is the alternative for IsMDIContainer in Windows 6.5 Mobile Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My knowledge is based on Windows Mobile 6.1 and earlier: The MDI Container is not available.

What you can do is place a number of Panels in your main form, call that main form MDI, paint the background Grey...

Before you know it, you think you have an MDI container!

Here are a couple of my projects. The older one is on the LEFT, the newer one (still incomplete) is on the RIGHT.

[image: screenshot1]  [image: screenshot2]

Comment: Thanks, It Worked after some modifications.